# How to write a script if water sensor comes into contact with water for more than 2 mins and LED lights up

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, shields, millis

I am a newbie to arduino and programming. I would like to come out with a code for water sensor to detect the presence of water for more than 2mins before lighting up the LED lightbulb. Currently using Arduino, Grove baseshield with grove water sensor http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Water_Sensor/.

I have the simple base code but not sure how do i go about adding in the function to detect water for a longer period of time before the light lights up:

```
#define watersensor 8               //Grove water sensor to Arduino Digital Pin 8
#define led 4                      //Grove LED to Digital Pin 4 

int isWater;
bool wasWater = false;
//bool isWater, wasWater = false;    // true => currently we are not seeing water
uint32_t waterstart_ms = 0;        // time first saw water


void setup() {
  pinMode(watersensor, INPUT);    
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);                   
}


void loop()
{
   // Is there water?
 isWater = digitalRead(watersensor);     // read sensor
 Serial.println(isWater);

   if( isWater ){
      if( wasWater ) {
      waterstart_ms = millis();  // First water: note the time
      }
        if( millis() - waterstart_ms >= 1*5*1000 ){// Water continues for 5s (trial first); time to light LED?
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        }//end if
            wasWater = true;
   } // end first if
   else {
      wasWater = false; // No water; LED off
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as how you do it for sound - just using the presence of water instead of the maximum value of sound.

Answer (score 1):

Should the LED be latched (stay on forever, once it's on), or go out if the sensor later detects no water? I'll assume the latter. Here's an (untested) state machine that should give you a good start. It keeps track of whether water was already seen, when it started, and whether it is seen now. There is some redundant switching of the LED; removing that (if desired) "is left as an exercise for the reader".

```
#define watersensor 8               //Grove water sensor to Arduino Digital Pin 8
#define led 4                      //Grove LED to Digital Pin 4 

#define TWOMIN (2*60*1000L)

bool isWater, wasWater = false;    // true => currently/were seeing water
uint32_t WaterStart_ms = 0;        // time first saw water


void setup() {
  pinMode(watersensor, INPUT_PULLUP);  // pullup for testing w/a button
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  // Is there water?
  isWater = !digitalRead(watersensor);     // read sensor

  if ( isWater ) {
    if ( !wasWater ){
      // First water: note the time
      WaterStart_ms = millis();
      wasWater = true;
    }
    else {
      // Water continues; time to light LED?
      if ( (millis() - WaterStart_ms) >= TWOMIN )
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
  }
  else {
    // No water; LED off
    wasWater = false;
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  delay(300);
}
```

Update:

Added `wasWater = true;` at line 27. The `delay(300)` at line 40 isn't necessary. Ran correctly when I tested it with a button (also negative logic) for the sensor.

> the light lights up randomly.

See if your sensor gives solid responses (try printing its output in loop() ). If it dithers around transitions, you may need to wait for some number of readings in a row that are opposite to the previous sensor state before you accept its new state as real.

Comment: Hi JRobert! Thanks for your guidance. I have made some minor amendments to the code. But the sensor only lights up without the presence of water. when i change the if ( !wasWater) to if (wasWater), the light lights up randomly. 

Not sure where went wrong..

Had updated the new amended code in my question!